# Half of approx symbol

Tags: formatting, accents, tilde

I would like to use half of the `\approx` approx symbol as an accent above a variable instead of `\sim`.

This is due to formatting reasons, see

[image]

The symbols are almost equivalent, however `\sim` is slightly more stretched vertically as far as I'm concerned.

Are there anyways to cut the `\approx` symbol in half or change the vertical scale of `\sim`? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you literally want to cut out the lower half, say, of `\approx`, `trimclip` may be what you are looking for. It allows you to clip away stuff from arbitrary boxes, of course including `\approx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\halfapprox}{\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.225em}{$\approx$}}
\begin{document}
$\halfapprox\approx$ 
\medskip

$\accentset{\halfapprox}{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Thanks to the comments by Bernard and Skydiver here is a perhaps more versatile version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{trimclip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\halfapprox}{\mathchoice{%
\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.22em}{$\displaystyle\approx$}}{%
\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.22em}{$\textstyle\approx$}}{%
\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.18em}{$\scriptstyle\approx$}}{%
\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.18em}{$\scriptscriptstyle\approx$}}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle\halfapprox\approx$ 
$\halfapprox\approx$ 
$\scriptstyle\halfapprox\approx$ 
$\scriptstyle\halfapprox\approx$ 
\medskip

$\accentset{\scriptstyle\halfapprox}{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, as clip is done by the viewer, you may see artifacts at certain zoom levels. Yet, according to what I find, at reasonably large zoom levels the above choices for the trim distances look fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Don't you think this \halfapprox should be in `\scriptscriptstyle`?

Comment: Yep, `\scriptscriptstyle` looks more like it. In this case, the command for `\halfapprox` would be `\newcommand{\halfapprox}{\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.14em}{$\scriptscriptstyle\approx$}}`

Comment: @Skydiver Or `\newcommand{\halfscriptapprox}{\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.16em}{$\scriptstyle\approx$}}`? (Will edit the answer later if that's OK.)

Comment: With my version `\halfapprox` becomes exactly the same size as `\approx`, which is what I was aiming for. But in the end it depends on what the end user wants to use this new tilde for, so it can of course be varied as one fancies.