# Triple Approx Symbol

Tags: math-mode, formatting, accents

I would like to generate a triple version of the approx symbol as an accent for math symbols. Thanks to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523669/half-of-approx-symbol), I already have half of an approx symbol, defined as

`\DeclareRobustCommand*{\halfapprox}{\clipbox{0em 0em 0em 0.14em}{$\scriptscriptstyle\approx$}}`.

However, when I use `\stackrel` to stack these symbols, the vertical space between them is too large.

`\DeclareRobustCommand*{\trtilde}[1]{\accentset{\stackrel{\halfapprox}{\approx}}{#1}}`

[image]

The other two symbols are defined by

`\DeclareRobustCommand*{\dbtilde}[1]{\accentset{\approx}{#1}}
 \DeclareRobustCommand*{\sgtilde}[1]{\accentset{\halfapprox}{#1}}`.

Is there an elegant way to define a triple approx symbol with accurate vertical spacing? If that's not possible, how can I adjust the vertical spacing of `\stackrel`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an answer, more for the unicode curious and the fonters -

There's a triple tilde mathematical operator in unicode (at U+224B) which, converted to an accent, in the various math fonts looks like this (if I've done it correctly - it's totally experimental):

[image: triple tilde accent]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{accents}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=blue]
\setmathfontface\masana{Asana Math}
\setmathfontface\mdejavu{DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mtgdeja{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\setmathfontface\mpagella{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfontface\mbonum{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\setmathfontface\mschola{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\setmathfontface\mtermes{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mlatin{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfontface\mcambria{Cambria Math}
\setmathfontface\mfira{Fira Math}
\setmathfontface\mfreeserif{FreeSerif}
\setmathfontface\mlibert{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfontface\mnoto{Noto Sans Symbols}
\setmathfontface\mqui{Quivira}
\setmathfontface\mstixtwo{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfontface\mstixgen{STIXGeneral}
\setmathfontface\msymbola{Symbola}
\setmathfontface\mgaramond{\detokenize{Garamond-Math}}
\newcommand\mfsize{\Huge}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

%Define \ttilde in unicode-math-table.tex:
%\UnicodeMathSymbol{"0224B}{\ttilde                    }{\mathaccent}{triple tilde accent}%

\newcommand\themassym{\accentset{\ttilde{}}{}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Sampling {\mfsize $\themassym $}}

\vspace{24pt}

\begin{tabular}{rccl}
XITS Math & \mfsize $\themassym$ & \mfsize $\mcambria \themassym$ & Cambria Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Asana Math & \mfsize $\masana {\themassym}$ & \mfsize $\mfira \themassym$ & Fira Math \\ 
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mdejavu \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mfreeserif \themassym$ & FreeSerif \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Bonum Math & \mfsize $\mbonum \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mlibert \themassym$ & Libertinus Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre DejaVu Math & \mfsize $\mtgdeja \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mnoto \themassym$ & Noto Sans Symbols \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Pagella Math & \mfsize $\mpagella \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mqui \themassym$ & Quivira \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Schola Math & \mfsize $\mschola \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mstixtwo \themassym$ &STIX Two Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Tex Gyre Termes Math & \mfsize $\mtermes \themassym$ & \mfsize $\mgaramond \themassym$ & Garamond-Math \\
\ &\ & \ & \ \\ 
Latin Modern Math & \mfsize $\mlatin \themassym$ & \mfsize $\msymbola \themassym$ & Symbola \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\tripprox}{\setbox0\hbox{$\approx$}%
\mbox{\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0.48\ht0}{$\approx$}}$\approx$}}
\begin{document}
\tripprox $\tripprox$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good approach, but why is the middle tilde vertically stretched? Would be perfect otherwise.

Comment: @Skydiver Apparently one has to raise the second \approx by a bit less than half of its height. That is, there is a tiny bit whitespace around the glyph.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! Just a note, if one wants to keep the original size of `approx`, it is necessary to put `\scriptscriptstyle` in front of every `\approx`. In this case, the correct value is 0.53 instead of 0.48.

Comment: You probably want to wrap this symbol in `\mathrel`.